# Use existing explorer.exe instance when calling from batch file - Windows 7

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

In my batch file, I am calling a new Windows file explorer at a specific location by using the following:

```
echo off
explorer.exe "C:/Users"
```

The user then navigates to other folders as needed. Then, when I call the batch file a second time I would like Windows to reuse the first instance of explorer.exe instead of launching another explorer.exe.

This will be the only copy of explorer.exe open on the computer at the time I run this batch file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **start** command to re-use instances of Windows file explorer.

Change your batch file to:

```
echo off 
start "C:\Users"
```

Comment: In my experience you have to add "" as a dumym first argument to strat, otherwise it will interpret the quoted path as the title to an empty process, rather than the proper resource to open.